# Html.RouteLink stops generating links after deployment to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

I'm developing an MVC 4 project to be deployed to Azure.

I have the following route configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BrowseBusinessByType", 
    url: "Browse/Business/ByType/{industry}/{region}/{city}/{page}",
    defaults: new
                  {
                      controller = "Browse",
                      action = "Business",
                      region = UrlParameter.Optional,
                      city = UrlParameter.Optional,
                      page = UrlParameter.Optional
                  }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BrowseBusinessByCity",
    url: "Browse/Business/ByCity/{region}/{city}/{industry}/{page}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Browse",
        action = "Business",
        industry = UrlParameter.Optional,
        city = UrlParameter.Optional,
        page = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
    );
```

There are more routes, but I swear the order is specific to generic, not otherwise.

On localhost, I use:

```
@Html.RouteLink(@String.Format("{0} ({1})", industryCount.Industry.Name,
industryCount.Count), new {
    Controller = "Browse",
    Action = "Business",
    industry = industryCount.Industry.Slug
})
```

to get the URL like

```
http://localhost:49311/Browse/Business/ByType/offices.
```

However, when delployed to Azure shared web site, the route becomes

```
http://www.zzzz.dd/Browse/Business?industry=offices
```

As routes are named, I tried to use

```
@Html.RouteLink(
    @String.Format("{0} ({1})", cityCount.City.Name, cityCount.Count),
    "BrowseBusinessByCity",
    new
    {
        region = cityCount.City.Region.Slug,
        city = cityCount.City.Slug,
    })
```

Which gives me

```
http://localhost:49311/Browse/Business/ByCity/eu/helsinki
```

on localhost and on deploy the html code for link is:

```
<a href="">London (8)</a>
```

What is even more challenging, my routes are completely functioning on URL (in Azure)

```
http://xxxx.dd/Browse/Business/ByCity/eu/helsinki
```

Phil Haack's routedebug2 output, Azure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzbgb.png

routedebug2, localhost:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kp3z.png

Thank you in advance for all your help!

**UP**:

I decided to publish web.configs in order to clear any doubts.

Debug:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BusinessDBEntities"
         connectionString="data source=ANDREW-PC\;initial catalog=BusinessCityEntities;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="azureStorageConnectionString"
         value="***" />

    <add key="azureContainer" value="thumbnails"/>

    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="RouteDebugger:Enabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
           modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
           preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
           modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
           preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Release:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BusinessDBEntities" connectionString="***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="DefaultConnection_ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="azureStorageConnectionString" value="***" />
    <add key="azureContainer" value="thumbnails" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="RouteDebugger:Enabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Regarding your route segments, each route should only have a maximum of 1 optional segment, and it must be the last segment in the route. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721994/asp-net-mvc-3-optional-parameter-routing-issue When you deploy to Azure, is your System.Web.Mvc.dll set to Copy Local?

Comment: @danludwig, thanks for joining my problem! It did work, really! Could you repost it as answer thus I'll be able to pick it as a correct answer to close my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because you have too many `UrlParameter.Optional` segments. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721994/asp-net-mvc-3-optional-parameter-routing-issue) for more info.